# C# Search multiline string for keyword and store variables

Tags: c#, string, split, multiline

I have a multi-line string that I get from a database.
This string would have a format like:

```
The below text is for the label program

COMPANY=ComanyName
PRODUCT=ProductName
SERIALMASK=123456789YYWWXXXX
```

How do I go through this text and store variables or an array with `ComanyName, ProductName, 123456789YYWWXXXX`, so I can insert these values into textboxes on my `Windows Forms Application`?

My big hurdle is that sometimes the format would be:

```
The below text is for the label program

Company1 Information: 
COMPANY=ComanyName 
PRODUCT=ProductName 
SERIALMASK=123456789YYWWXXXX

Company2 Information: 
COMPANY=ComanyName 
PRODUCT=ProductName 
SERIALMASK=123456789YYWWXXXX
```

And in that case, I only wanna extract the first occurance of `COMPANY`, `PRODUCT` and `SERIALMASK` variables.

Now I have code that save each line in a variables, and I guess I could run a switch-case function in the foreach loop and look for substring. But I am hoping there is a more effective way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "COMPANY=ComanyName\n" +
                "PRODUCT=ProductName\n" +
                "SERIALMASK=123456789YYWWXXXX\n";

            string pattern = @"(?'name'\w+)=(?'value'\w+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input,pattern);

            foreach(Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', Value : '{1}'", match.Groups["name"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["name"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant to use regular expressions looking for the format of the line. :)
This works beautifully.
I have made a `foreach (var entry in dict) {}` with a `switch-case` looking for the Key I need to input the values into textboxes. And everything works like it should.

But I was wondering. Is there some way of extracting the values like:
`textBox.Text = dict-where-key=COMPANY.Value` :)
Or is my way just as efficient?

Comment: Enumerate on the keys : string v = dict.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Value == "ProductName").Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Thanks jdweng. Great idea.
Worked perfectly, with a minor correction.  `string v = dict.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Key == "PRODUCT").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();`
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: If you want to lookup by key it is simply string v = dict["PRODUCT"];

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it would throw an exception if there wasn't any key with that name. 
By using it the other way, it shows up as empty if there is no match.

Comment: This is a little better : string vv = dict.ContainsKey("PRODUCT") ? dict["PRODUCT"] : string.Empty;

Comment: That works beautifully as well, and is a bit more readable :) Thank you very much jdweng.

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you

```
string allText = File.ReadAllText("JsonFound.txt");
List<string> allrecord = allText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Where(x => x.Contains(":"))
                                .ToList();
List<CompanyInfo> CompanyInfos = new List<CompanyInfo>();
List<string> infos = new List<string>();
foreach(string s in allrecord)
{
    infos = s.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Skip(Math.Max(0, 1))
                       .SelectMany(q=>q.Split('='))
             .ToList();

    CompanyInfo ci = new CompanyInfo();
    ci.CompanyName = infos[1];
    ci.ProductName = infos[3];
    ci.SerialMaskNumber = infos[5];
    CompanyInfos.Add(ci);
}
```

The Class `CompanyInfo` would look like this

```
public class CompanyInfo
{
    public string CompanyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ProductName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string SerialMaskNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. It looks like a good solution, if I could trust that the information is stored in the exact same order, with CompanyName, ProductName and SerialMaskNumber. But if someone enter the information in another order, I would get the wrong information with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the HashSet function. The list contains no duplicate records.

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<CompanyInfo>(CompanyInfos);
```